# SketchUp How to Remove the Mesh Lines

Tags: 3d, sketchup

I am using SketchUp to import from models. No matter what I do I get those Mesh grid lines for each of my model as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Is there anyway to remove those because they are even exported to the final DAE format model.

When I export to DAE format using SketUp I see the following DAE file preview:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Soften / Smooth Edges feature.  Select your component, right click and choose Soften / Smooth Edges.  This will open the Soften Edges tray (assuming you are using SketchUp 2018).
Make sure "Smooth Normals" is checked and then adjust the Angle slider until you get the result you want.  Typically a value between 30 deg and 60 deg works best.  Going past 90 will usually give you weird results.